# Proving unit circle without y axis but with 0 is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm doing Baby Rudin chapter 2 exercise 20 and trying to show that a set being connected doesn't imply that its interior is connected. The counter example I'd like to prove is the unit circle minus the y axis but plus the 0 point, ie
$$E = \{ x \in R^2 : dist(x,\textbf{0}) < 1 \land x_1 \neq 0 \} \cup \{ \textbf{0}\}$$
where $$x_1$$ is the x coordinate of the point in $$R^2$$
Intuitively E seems connected, as all the points on the left of the y axis touch each other, and likewise the points on the right, and the two sets are connected by the 0 point. Its interior isn't connected, as it will exclude the 0 point, and the sets
$$\{ x \in R^2 : dist(x,\textbf{0}) < 1 \land x_1 < 0 \} \qquad \{ x \in R^2 : dist(x,\textbf{0}) < 1 \land x_1 > 0 \}$$
are separated.
But I'm not sure how to prove that E is connected. For contradiction, assuming it isn't means that for some A and B whose union is E, they are disjoint and neither contains a limit point of the other, so each point x in A has a neighborhood without any points in B and vice versa. This feels like a promising road to go down but I'm not really sure where to go from there. Any advice?

Edit: Rudin's definition for E being connected is that no A and B whose union equals E are separated, where separated means that A union closure B is disjoint, and B union closure A is disjoint. I've seen that there are other definitions but would like to try to prove things with this one, or at least tie back other definitions to this one.

Comment: That seems correct to me. Another example would be a dumbell shape: two closed discs connected by a line between them.

Comment: Let $A$ be the left half plus origin. It is connected as $\textbf{0}$ is in the closure of the left half, which is connected (and if $A$ is connected and $A \subseteq C \subseteq \overline{A}$, $C$ is connected). Similarly for $B$ the right half plus $\textbf{0}$. Your set is their union which is connected as they intersect.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the concept of path-connectedness? Recall that a path-connected space is connected. Given this, we have a path between every two points $y_0$ and $y_1$ in $E$ by first passing from $y_0$ to $x_1$ using a line segment in time $\frac{1}{2}$, and then passing from $x_1$ to $y_1$ using another line segment again in time $\frac{1}{2}$.

---

If you aren't familiar with path-connected spaces, here are the relevant facts.

**Definition 1**. A space $X$ is path-connected if for each pair $y_0, y_1 \in X$ there exists a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to X$ such that $f(0) = y_0$ and $f(1) = y_1$.

**Lemma 2**. A path-connected space $X$ is connected. (Exercise: show that the converse is not true.)

*Proof.* Suppose that $X$ is path-connected and also that $X = U \cup V$ for $U$ and $V$ disjoint open sets in $X$. Suppose for a contradiction that neither $U$ not $V$ is empty and let $y_0 \in U$ and $y_1 \in V$. Then by hypothesis there exists a continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to X$ such that $f(0) = y_0$ and $f(1) = y_1$. By the definition of a continuous function in particular the preimages $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are both open subsets of $[0, 1]$, and because $X$ is the union of $U$ and $V$, the union $f^{-1}(U) \cup f^{-1}(V)$ is $[0, 1]$. But the preimages $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are also disjoint subsets of $[0, 1]$! Because $[0, 1]$ is connected, one of the sets $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ must be empty, which is the desired contradiction (because $0 \in U$ and $1 \in V$). This completes the proof.

Comment: I haven't seen that definition, can you point me to a statement of the definition and a proof that it implies connectedness?

Comment: @TsviBenschar sure, I'll just write one down.

Comment: @TsviBenschar There you go: the notion of path-connectedness is very useful when you are dealing with most "reasonable" topological spaces.

Comment: Rudin hasn't defined function continuity yet lol, I know what it is intuitively from calc but not sure i could write rigorous proofs with it

Comment: @TsviBenschar I see---for your information so that what is going on isn't mysterious: a function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous if the preimage of every open set of $Y$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Kit-Wing Yu provides the following answer in A Complete Solution Guide to Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Let $E$ be a connected set. Assume $\overline{E}=A \cup B$, where $\overline{A}\cap B = A \cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$. Since $A\cap E\subseteq A$ and $B\cap E \subseteq B$, we have $\overline{A\cap E} \subseteq \overline{A}$ and $\overline{B\cap E} \subseteq \overline{B}$. Since $A\subseteq \overline{A}$, we have $A\cap B\subseteq \overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset$. Since $E \subseteq \overline{E}=A\cup B$, we have

$$E=E\cap\overline{E}=E\cap (A\cup B)=(A\cap A)\cup (E\cap B).$$

Since $(\overline{A\cap E})\cap (B\cap E)\subseteq \overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset$ and $(\overline{B\cap E})\cap (A\cap E)\subseteq \overline{B}\cap A = \emptyset$, we have $E$ is disconnected, which is a contradiciton. Hence, $\overline{E}$ must be connected.

Now suppose that $A$ and $B$ are connected sets and $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$. Then the set $E=A\cup B$ is also connected.

Consider $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}| |x|\leq 1\}$, $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}| |x-(2,0)|\leq 1\}$ and $E=A\cup B$. $E$ is connected but $E^{\circ}$ is not.